# Is there a way to restore the cycles render settings to default?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I need to start afresh. I'm having a problem with alpha transparency and volume scatter.

Comment: To reset blender use File > Load Factory Settings. To reset the nodes (but keep them connected) see: [**Reset nodes to their default values**](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42306/reset-nodes-to-their-default-values)

Comment: But if you add more detail to your question and explain in detail what your problem is (and show some images, or share a blend file) maybe someone can find a solution.

Comment: Ah, that's it. I was looking in user preferences. I've got the main problem here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76346/alpha-transparency-lightening-and-volume-scatter But the problem is elusive, sometimes showing up and sometimes not, like a car when you bring it to a mechanic. I'm hoping starting with default settings will help me isolate the problem. Thanks you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reset nodes to their default values](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42306/reset-nodes-to-their-default-values)

Comment: Maybe this can help too https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47343/how-to-append-cycles-render-settings-to-another-file/47371#47371 you can then link all your objects to a new scene with default values, effectively resetting them to whatever you want, default or otherwise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append cycles render settings to another file](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47343/how-to-append-cycles-render-settings-to-another-file)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, I don't think there is.

You can load a .blend file without the saved UI, but this doesn't include settings in the render property panel (which is what I think you are getting at). These cannot (as far as I know) be divorced from the other data in the file.

You would probably need to create a new empty file (which should load default settings for everything), and then use File->Append to import the objects from your other .blend file into that new file.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for cycles I don't think there's a reset defaults function but what you can do is this:

- Open a new blender project
- File -> Defaults -> Load Factory Settings
- append collections from already created project